# In Python3 the behaviour of the inbuilt repr() function has changed when compared to Python2

Tags: python-3.x, repr

In Python3 the behaviour of the inbuilt repr() function has changed when compared to Python2.

In python2

```
repr("Дует Світязь")
"'\\xd0\\x94\\xd1\\x83\\xd0\\xb5\\xd1\\x82 \\xd0\\xa1\\xd0\\xb2\\xd1\\x96\\xd1\\x82\\xd1\\x8f\\xd0\\xb7\\xd1\\x8c'"
```

In Python3

```
repr("Дует Світязь")
"'Дует Світязь'"
```

How can I get repr() to work in Python3 the same as in Python2 or as an alternative another method to convert a string to escaped characters
In my code. I use the escaped characters in lookup tables for my LCD display translation routines.

The platform is Raspberry Pi OS(Raspbian).

I have also tried using reprlib() without success. It gives the same output as repr(). Using string.encode goes some way to proving a solution, but the result is different to Python2 repr()

```
txt = "Дует Світязь"
txt.encode('utf8')
b'\xd0\x94\xd1\x83\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82 \xd0\xa1\xd0\xb2\xd1\x96\xd1\x82\xd1\x8f\xd0\xb7\xd1\x8c'
```

Comment: “_repr() to work in Python3 the same as in Python2_“ - I don’t think you can. Upgrades do come at some cost.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the string as bytes object:

```
print('Дует Світязь'.encode('utf-8'))
```

Prints:

```
b'\xd0\x94\xd1\x83\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82 \xd0\xa1\xd0\xb2\xd1\x96\xd1\x82\xd1\x8f\xd0\xb7\xd1\x8c'
```

---

EDIT:

```
s = str('Дует Світязь'.encode('utf-8')).lstrip('b').replace('\\', r'\\')
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
'\\xd0\\x94\\xd1\\x83\\xd0\\xb5\\xd1\\x82 \\xd0\\xa1\\xd0\\xb2\\xd1\\x96\\xd1\\x82\\xd1\\x8f\\xd0\\xb7\\xd1\\x8c'
```

Comment: string.encode() unfortunately doesn't give the same results as repr() and would mean amending over a thousand lines in my translation tables, so I am keen to get repr() to work the same as in Python2.

Comment: @BobRathbone See my edit. Is this the result you want?

Comment: Many thanks.  The above goes some way towards solving the problem but string.encode() produces a byte representation, repr() produces an ascii string string. However I can probably find a way around that.

Answer (score 0):

My thanks to Andrej Kesely who put me on the right path for a solution

In Python2

```
s = repr(text)
```

In Python3

```
s = str(text.encode('utf-8')).lstrip('b')
```

I don't really understand why the authors of Python3 felt the need to change how a built in function such as repr() works. No doubt they have their reasons.